# Problema al devolver datos de un FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

Tengo un problema en flutter a la hora de recorrer un Future para rellenar un SliverGrid. Les muestro un poco de código:

```
SliverGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: [
    FutureBuilder(
      future: _productoProvider.getProductos(categoria.pk),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductoModel>> snapshot){
        if ( snapshot.hasData ){
          print(snapshot.data.length);
          for (var i = 0; i< snapshot.data.length; i++){
            return Text(snapshot.data[i].nombre);
          }
        }                  
      },
    ),
    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
    Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
    Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
  ],
),
```

El problema es que úncamente escribe el primero (sale por el return y deja de iterar).

Comment: Al hacer el return estás entregando un resultado, por ende sería correcto el comportamiento actual. ¿Qué intentas hacer?

Comment: Entiendo que es lo normal, pero al estar dentro del builder, pensé que recorrería todos los elementos. Lo que necesito que que me devuelva los 4 valores que hay en el snapshot.data.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que cambiar el `FutureBuilder` para que este encima del `GridView` así puedes controlar los elementos, de la siguiente manera:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
            future: _productoProvider.getProductos(categoria.pk),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List< ProductoModel >> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print(snapshot.data.length);
                final widgets = List<Widget>();
                for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
                  widgets.add(Text(snapshot.data[i].nombre));
                }
                return GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 3, children: [
                  ...widgets,
                  Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
                  Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
                  Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
                ]);
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          )
```

En el ejemplo estoy usando `GridView.count`, funciona si es que no usas `Slivers`.

Si todo está dentro un CustomScrollView y necesitas Slivers, puedes usar SliverToBoxAdapter
 Y agregaf el FutureBuilder dentro con GridView.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. El problema es que todo está dentro de un CustomScrollView (con slivers), y no admite un FutureBuilder... Una posible solución sería usando un StateFulWidget, calculando antes el length y modificando por setState para así utilidar un SliverGird normal con su childCount, pero es un Widget normal, no una clase. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta